# How to create another widgets.php page

Tags: widgets

Is it possible to create another widgets.php page? say widgets-ads.php?

I want to make it for displaying ads in my website by drag and drop of widgets in a predefined sidebars.

Comment: I'm going to guess what you want is to create new widgets, which you can do extending the WP_Widget class with the [Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).  Take a look at [default-widgets.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-widgets.php) and see how the widgets bundled with WordPress are coded and go from there.

Comment: You can also register new sidebars using the Widgets API

Comment: It's not about using the same widgets.php page in the admincp, it's about creating a new widgets page with sidebars and widgets in it, separated from the default widgets.php.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to create widget areas and new widgets http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

Comment: Answers like rely on links aren't very helpful because if the link goes bad or changes, the answer becomes useless.  Maybe you could add some example code for registering a new widget and explain the process?

Comment: even if that is a codex link?  would it be better if I took that same info and pasted it here?  what about the Widgets API link you gave?

Comment: I gave it in a comment.  Even if it's the codex, yes, see [how to answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).  And welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: yes, well, the only way i could add a comment was to have more rep :) which i could not do yet :) so i was looking to just add a 'comment' and found this was the only way... sorry for barging, and thanks for the welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not into coding you can simply use a plugin that permits multiple sidebars. Go to the Plugin repository and search for sidebars. Several of the plugins permit the establishment of multiple sidebars and permit using a different sidebar on on each page/post/category. Then just put different widgets in each sidebar to have the ads change.

Or, going another way use a plugin like Widget Visibility to use a single sidebar and then set a particular widget to display only on specific pages/posts. This capability is also included in a Jetpack module.